# React router dom v6 multiple optional parameters works locally but not in production

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom` with multiple optional parameters because the regular queryString parameters are not working in my app due to some other logic.

This is working locally, but not after build.

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      exact 
      path=':param1?/:param2?/:param3?/:param4?'
      element={<Main className={styles.main} />}
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

To be precise, the first optional parameter (`param1`) is working fine in production, but when adding a second, I get a blank page in production.

I am getting the following error messages but I am not sure how to solve them. I am not getting any of those errors with just the first parameter or without any parameters at all.

[image]

Does anyone know what could cause this?

I have the following code in htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]

#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
# Section managed by cPanel: Password Protected Directories     -cp:ppd
# - Do not edit this section of the htaccess file!              -cp:ppd
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd
# End section managed by cPanel: Password Protected Directories -cp:ppd
#----------------------------------------------------------------cp:ppd

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the password"
AuthUserFile REDACTEDFORPRIVACY/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue, problem for me was twofold:

1. that scripts and styles were imported from

**website.com/parameter1/parameter2/script** rather than from **website.com/script**

solved it by adding base url in public/index.html as `'/'`:

```
 <base href="/" />
```

and changing output/publicurl to `'/'` in webpack-config.js (in modules/react-scripts/config)

```
output: {
      publicPath: '/',
}
```

If you host on a subdomain, use `'/subdomain/'` instead of `'/'`

2. That manifest.json needs the crossorigin tag in public/index.html

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials" />
```